# Should I buy a flight ticket before I apply for my visa?

Tags: visas, air-travel, application-status

I am traveling through Schengen (Germany) and I have to extend my visa and immigration needs to see an itinerary. If they do not allow me to extend, I will need another ticket - so I don't want to pay for this before I hear back about the visa.

Should I buy a flight ticket before I apply for my visa ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you already in the Schengen area? If so, on what type of visa?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little known fact that most full service airlines will refund your ticket if you can prove that you were denied a visa, and you do not need to buy a refundable ticket to rely on this. The only exception I know of is Saudia (SV), which explicitly does not allow this. (Probably because obtain Saudi visas is not easy.)

You should certainly check, and it may be buried deep in the terms and conditions, but if such a provision applies then there is no harm in buying your ticket as normal in advance.

Your alternative is to buy a fully flexible completely refundable ticket. Once immigration issue your visa, cancel it for a refund and buy the cheapest ticket available.

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen visa application requires a airline *reservation* not a ticket. You don't have to buy a ticket; simply show proof of a reservation.

Here is a snippet from a [pdf of requirements for the Netherlands](http://kuwait.nlembassy.org/binaries/content/assets/postenweb/k/koeweit/netherlands-embassy-in-kuwait/import/visa_for_the_netherlands/all_other_visas/visa-requirements-schengen.pdf) and I have emphasized the relevant part:

> 1. Duly filled application form with 1 recent photograph (NOT OLDER THEN 6 MONTHS) with white or grey background color passport size.
> 2. Passport valid at least 3 months after expiry date of the visa.
> 3. Copy of holder page travel document.
> 4. Copy of ID card if applicable.
> 5. Previous passport if any.
> 6. **Copy of flight reservation** and hotel booking for the entire period of stay in Schengen Area.
> 7. Copy of travel insurance, minimum coverage €30,000 (thirty thousand) valid for Schengen Area for the duration of your stay